# how to display list of notification alerts one by one from activity?

Tags: android, list, notifications

i am new programmer in android application i would like display multiple notifications one by one from activity.i have implemented a method to get the notification as follows

```
       public void myNotify(String message) {

    Log.v("my notification method","from GetNotification class");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)       getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            "check the notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(""));
    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, message,
            "for more info run ur app", activity);
    notification.number += 1;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);



}
```

and i have used a string array to display the notifications as a list the following code for display notifications

```
       String[] msg={"hai","how are you?","wer r u?","what is going on","how is this?","let we talk?","nothing is there","hahaha"}; 
    Thread rt=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                for(int i1=0;i1<msg.length;i1++){

                    Log.v("", "thread running"+i1);

                    myNotify(msg[i1]);  

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    rt.start();
```

from above code i would like to display notifications alerts list one by one as follows:

hai

how are you?

wer r u?

what is going on

how is this?

........

how can i display the String array values as notifications as list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. I think you are asking how you can show notifications and have them remain, so as you show more notifications they do not remove the previous ones. i.e. each time you show a notification it's added to the list without replacing the existing one.  If so, you do that like this:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
notificationManager.notify(3, notification);
```

By providing a different identifier to each notification, they are displayed separately.